# Generating a custom ID based on other columns in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas df which looks like this

```
   UID    DOB        BEDNUM     
    0   1900-01-01    CICU1   
    1   1927-05-21    CICU1 
    2   1929-10-03    CICU1 
    3   1933-06-29    CICU1 
    4   1936-01-09    CICU1 
    5   1947-11-14    CICU1   
    6   1900-01-01    CICU1   
    7   1927-05-21    CICU1 
    8   1929-10-03    CICU1 
    9   1933-06-29    CICU1 
   10   1936-01-09    CICU1 
   11   1947-11-14    CICU1
```

Now I would like to add a new column TID to that data frame which should be in 'YYYY-0000000-P' format

```
    UID    DOB        BEDNUM    TID 
    0   1900-01-01    CICU1   1900-0000000-P
    1   1927-05-21    CICU1   1927-0000001-P
    2   1929-10-03    CICU1   1929-0000002-P
    3   1933-06-29    CICU1   1933-0000003-P
    4   1936-01-09    CICU1   1936-0000004-P
    5   1947-11-14    CICU1   1947-0000005-P
    6   1900-01-01    CICU1   1900-0000006-P
    7   1927-05-21    CICU1   1927-0000007-P
    8   1929-10-03    CICU1   1929-0000008-P
    9   1933-06-29    CICU1   1933-0000009-P
   10   1936-01-09    CICU1   1936-0000010-P
   11   1947-11-14    CICU1   1947-0000011-P
```

I have 24000 records in a table and the last record TID should look like 'YYYY-0024000-P'.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this. 
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using Pandas `str` methods:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])  # convert DOB to datetime if necessary

df['TID'] = df['DOB'].dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df['UID'].astype(str).str.zfill(7) + '-P'

print(df)

    UID        DOB BEDNUM  Year             TID
0     0 1900-01-01  CICU1  1900  1900-0000000-P
1     1 1927-05-21  CICU1  1927  1927-0000001-P
2     2 1929-10-03  CICU1  1929  1929-0000002-P
3     3 1933-06-29  CICU1  1933  1933-0000003-P
4     4 1936-01-09  CICU1  1936  1936-0000004-P
5     5 1947-11-14  CICU1  1947  1947-0000005-P
6     6 1900-01-01  CICU1  1900  1900-0000006-P
7     7 1927-05-21  CICU1  1927  1927-0000007-P
8     8 1929-10-03  CICU1  1929  1929-0000008-P
9     9 1933-06-29  CICU1  1933  1933-0000009-P
10   10 1936-01-09  CICU1  1936  1936-0000010-P
11   11 1947-11-14  CICU1  1947  1947-0000011-P
```

Comment: Should be faster, because it is vectorized?

Comment: @MisterMonk, No, Pandas `str` methods are not vectorised. A list comprehension with built-in `str` methods only + f-strings is probably faster.

Comment: Ah nice to know

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes that `DOB` is `datetime`:

```
year = df.DOB.dt.year
nums = df.UID.astype(str).str.zfill(7)
df.assign(TID=[f'{y}-{num}-P' for y, num in zip(year, nums)])
```

```
    UID        DOB BEDNUM             TID
0     0 1900-01-01  CICU1  1900-0000000-P
1     1 1927-05-21  CICU1  1927-0000001-P
2     2 1929-10-03  CICU1  1929-0000002-P
3     3 1933-06-29  CICU1  1933-0000003-P
4     4 1936-01-09  CICU1  1936-0000004-P
5     5 1947-11-14  CICU1  1947-0000005-P
6     6 1900-01-01  CICU1  1900-0000006-P
7     7 1927-05-21  CICU1  1927-0000007-P
8     8 1929-10-03  CICU1  1929-0000008-P
9     9 1933-06-29  CICU1  1933-0000009-P
10   10 1936-01-09  CICU1  1936-0000010-P
11   11 1947-11-14  CICU1  1947-0000011-P
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `.str` accessor:

```
year = df.DOB.str.split('-').str[0]
padded_uid = df.UID.astype(str).str.pad(7, 'left', '0')
df['TID'] = year + '-' + padded_uid + '-P'
```